# What will be the shape of liquid if there is no gravitational force

Tags: newtonian-gravity, surface-tension

We all know that liquid will take a shape of container in which its filled, but What will be the shape of liquid if there is no gravitational force?

Comment: Also related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/33768/

Comment: You have to define your problem better: is the liquid still in the container?

Comment: The lumps of liquid will get a spherical shape if they are not disturbed due to the attraction between the water molecules an their surface tension

Comment: They will get spherical shape also because the sphere has the least surface area for a given volume.

Answer (score 0):

Partially depends on the liquid , since the adhesive and cohesive properties will change the shape as well as the mass of the liquid. But the basic shape will be spherical in shape with the size depending on the liquid. Please state your question better such as wether it is still in the container etc